# expression expected '{' - having string and int together

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, int

making a table, when added rows, got an error,

code is:

```
    For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
       table2.Rows.Add ({row(0), row(1)})

     Next
```

expression expected

```
     table2.Rows.Add (***{****row(0), row(1)})
```

am having an error saying expression expected on the "{"

i think i no why this is, its because row(0) is string and row(1) is an int.

therefore how would i apply it to one being a string and one being a int.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use some form of initializer syntax there, but it's not clear whether you've forgotten to name the object you're initializing or just somehow expected it to work outside of an initialization situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataTable.Rows.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wwak56.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) method requires an array of objects (one object for each column) so your code could be simply

```
table2.Rows.Add (row(0), row(1))
```

By the way, if you are trying to copy from one table to another take a look at the built-in methods [DataTable.Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx) or [DataTable.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy.aspx) as well [DataTable.LoadDataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcy03ww2.aspx) and [DataTable.ImportRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow.aspx)

Comment: quick question, as this copies all the column, how would i only just select the first column of the 2nd row. rather than the whole column?

Comment: DataTable.Select(filterexpression) if it is the result of a search  or just DataTable.Rows(1)(0). But a correct answer requires more context (which is your requirement, better to post a new question)